# Sending attachments as an email from a form - NOT from local files

Tags: jakarta-mail, attachment

I have created a HTML email form which allows a user to enter To, subject, message, content and attachments however I cannot get the attachments to send.
I have researched online and came across many variations of this code:

```
     messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     String filename = "/home/manisha/file.txt";
     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
     messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
     messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

But is there a way of sending attachments input into the form instead of adding the file path to a file in the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, the files need to be uploaded from the browser to the server using the html form.  Depending on what you're using to manage the uploaded data, you can store the file data in memory or in files on the server.  If you store it in memory, you can use a [ByteArrayDataSource](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html) instead of FileDataSource in your code above.

Comment: changing "DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);" to  ' ByteArrayDataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(filename);' is causing errors in my code. And I don't know what to set String filename = ""?
Can you offer any further advice?

Comment: What errors?  Did you read the javadocs for ByteArrayDataSource so you know how to use it?